How to install pytorch compatible with CUDA 11.7?
I have "NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2070" GPU on my machine. I found CUDA 11.7 is the latest version of CUDA thats compatible with this GPU and works with pytorch. I have installed CUDA 11.7. Now I am trying to install pytorch that works with CUDA 11.7.
I tried this:
pip install torch torchvision torchaudio --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu117
But I am only getting cpu version: 2.3.1+cpu
I also tried through conda and thats didnt help either:
conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=11.7 -c pytorch
How do I get the GPU compatible version?

have you tried pip install torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu117 (note: no extra)

pip install torch==2.0.1 torchvision==0.15.2 torchaudio==2.0.2 would fit to your environment I search. The latest torch version might not support the old driver version.

This works for me if you precise versions:
pip install torch==2.0.0+cu117 --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu117
pip install torchvision==0.15.0+cu117 --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu117

Didn’t check the compatible torchaudio version though.
